# My contact HTML page redirects to my contact PHP and doesn't send email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my contact form to work. When I fill out the form and click "send" it redirects to the `contact.php` and doesn't send email or work. Can anyone help me and explain what's wrong with my code? This is the code below:

```
<div id="zContact_form">                        
    <center><?php echo $text;?></center>                    
    <strong>We will reply within 15 minutes, that's a Promise!!.    </strong>
    <form name="form1" id="ff" method="post"     action="contact.php">
        <label>
            Name*:
            <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name"     name="name" id="name" required>
        </label>

        <label>
            Email*:
            <input type="email" placeholder="info@youbelizetours.com" name="email" id="email" required>
        </label>

        <label>
            Message*:
            <textarea name="message" id="message">Please enter your message</textarea>
        </label>

        <input class="sendButton" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">      
    </form>

<?php
    $text = "<span style='color:red; font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; magin: 10px;'>Error! Please try again.</span>";

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $message=$_POST['message'];
        $to = "youbelizetours@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Tour Reservations from Edwin's Adventure Tours";
        $message = " Name: " . $name ."\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Message:\r\n" . $message;
        $from = "$name";
        $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

        if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
            $text = "<span style='color:blue; font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; margin: 10px;'>Your Message was sent successfully !</span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? or may it be something else I'm not seeing.

Comment: the code `<span style='color:blue; font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; margin: 10px;'>Your Message was sent successfully !</span>` is rendered?

Comment: Add `}` at the end of the php. (You're missing a closing bracket)

Comment: When sending emails with php, I had problems with '@hotmail.com' rejecting the emails that were sent. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

What i can see is missing closing bracket for $_POST in the last. rest code seems fine to me provided contact.php is separate file or entire code is in contact.php. I tested the code using `form action=""`

```
<?php
$text = "<span style='color:red; font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; magin: 10px;'>Error! Please try again.</span>";

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];

    $to = "youbelizetours@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Tour Reservations from Edwin's Adventure Tours";
    $message = " Name: " . $name ."\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Message:\r\n" . $message;

    $from = "$name";
    $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
      $text = "<span style='color:blue; font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; margin: 10px;'>Your Message was sent successfully !</span>";
    }
}
?>
<div id="zContact_form">            
    <center><?php echo $text;?></center>
    <strong>We will reply within 15 minutes, that's a Promise!!.</strong>

    <form name="form1" id="ff" method="post" action="">
    <label>
    Name*:
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name" name="name" id="name" required>
    </label>

    <label>
    Email*:
    <input type="email" placeholder="info@youbelizetours.com" name="email" id="email" required>
    </label>

    <label>
    Message*:
    <textarea name="message" id="message">Please enter your message</textarea>
    </label>
    <input class="sendButton" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
```